# Can I call a jekyll page attribute within a for statement

Tags: static, yaml, markdown, jekyll, jekyll-paginator

```
{% for item in site.data.{{page.ocean}}.section %}
```

This is not working for me. I'm using `page.ocean` at other places in the page and it works fine. I'm not sure if I can do this within a for statement. If not, is there a way to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% assign ocean = page.ocean %}
{% for item in site.data[ocean].section %}
  <!-- your code -->
{% endfor %}
```

Check [Liquid's Variable](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/variable/) and yes we can access data variable content like an Array through indexing.